# Display an avergae using PHP and SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a website with a friend and I need to display the average rating for a movie.

So, I have a database with numerous columns (name, mail, etc) including "note".

My friend wrote this code :

```
<?php 
$moyenne = "SELECT avg(note) FROM `annee_1`";
$test = $db->prepare($moyenne);
$test->execute();
$resultat = $test->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $resultat;
?>
```

I'm not overly familiar with php or mysql. I know something is wrong (since this doesn't display a number, but just "Array"), but I don't know what.

Any suggestiong, or solution to my problem?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: which column is used to store `rating`?

Comment: `fetchAll()` returns an array of rows (in this case it should be one row). Try `print_r($resultat);` to see what the array contains and how to access the actual value.

Comment: `echo $resultat[0]['avg(note)'];` Run that and it will suddenly start to make a lot of sense

Comment: The column used to store rating is "note".

Comment: It would also help if you can show us your table structure of `annee_1`. As @rickdenhaan already said - fetchAll returns an array, your result is most likely in `$resultat[0]['avg(note)']`

Answer (score 1):

You can access to your result by passing parameter to your array with a while loop. Replace your echo $result by `print_r($resultat)` and you can check the  result you have received.

Comment: That helped a lot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query will return one row with one column. An easy way to get a single value from a query like that is to use

```
$resultat = $test->fetchColumn();
```

Instead of

```
$resultat = $test->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You're seeing "Array" currently because `$resultat` is an array (because that's what `fetchAll` reutrns), and when you try to `echo` it, it gets converted to a string. In PHP, the string representation of any array is "Array". [See the documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting):

> Arrays are always converted to the string "Array"; because of this, echo and print can not by themselves show the contents of an array.

But if you use [`fetchColumn()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) instead, `$resultat` won't be an array. Based on your comments, it should be an int.